# Laravel Varbox fresh installation failed

Tags: laravel, installation

I’ve downloaded the free version of Varbox wanting to start a new project using this platform that seems to be Laravel based, but it seems that after install I don't see the specific Laravel homepage, as I'd expect from a Laravel project.

I’ve setup a git repository with the Varbox source code, but it doesn’t seem to be a working Laravel project (eg. it doesn’t have an `.env` file, `php artisan` is not accessible).

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't attempt to use Varbox as a monolithic application.

Varbox has been designed as a **Composer package** which you'll have to locally require in your own Laravel projects, so that means you'll need to already have a working Laravel projects on top of which to install Varbox.

[please click to see what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS82j.png)

Please follow the documentation (I suggest installing it in the automatic way, as it's less time consuming): https://varbox.io/docs/1.x/installation